# Relativity and the addition of speed

Tags: faster-than-light

Two rockets, that can each travel slightly faster than half of the speed of light, are launched from opposite sides of the planet.

Why isn't rocket A traveling faster than the speed of light relative to rocket B?

Comment: Why slightly fast then half?  Why not go all out and say that each rocket is launched with a speed of $c - \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is vanishingly small?  It's still the case that either rocket observes the other to have speed less than $c$.

Comment: Why was my comment deleted from here?